# Retrieving an autocomplete value with cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

there's this website that conjugates korean verbs https://www.verbix.com/languages/korean. What i wanna do is type something in the input and then get the text of the suggestion that appears.
[image]

That blue part is the 'a' element's text
[image]

This is my code:

```
app.get("/conjugation", (req, res) => {
  axios("https://www.verbix.com/languages/korean")
    .then((response) => {
      const htmlData = response.data;
      const $ = cheerio.load(htmlData);
      //Input Element
      const input = $("#auto-complete-edit");
      //Pass the value to it
      input.attr("value", "먹어요");
      //Get the selected element
      const select = $(".selected");
      select
        .map((i, child) => {
          //Get the 'a' element inner text
          return $(child).find("a").text();
        })
        .get();
      console.log(select);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

And the console shows this

```
LoadedCheerio {
  length: 0,
  options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
  _root: <ref *1> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Document {
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      startIndex: null,
      endIndex: null,
      children: [Array],
      type: 'root',
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *1]
  },
  prevObject: <ref *2> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Document {
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      startIndex: null,
      endIndex: null,
      children: [Array],
      type: 'root',
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *2]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix '$(...).click is not a function' in Node/Cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675374/how-to-fix-click-is-not-a-function-in-node-cheerio)

Comment: Cheerio can't interact with the page or perform form submissions or execute JS. See [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)